# translationY equivalent to actually affect the layout

Tags: qt, blackberry, blackberry-10, cascade, blackberry-cascades

As per the definition of translationY: `The translation is mostly useful for animations as it doesn't affect the actual laid out position of the visual node. This translation is added after the node has been laid out so it doesn't affect layout in any way`

Is there any property that actually affect the position of the visual node?

What I want is the text of the label to start from its top border. If I use `translationY`, it touches the top border but the size of the label remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is thin on specifics but if you use [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__absolutelayout.html) the members of [AbsoluteLayoutProperties](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__absolutelayoutproperties.html) can affect the laid out position of a visual node as in the following QML:

```
Container {
    layout: AbsoluteLayout {}

    Label {
        text: "Label"
        layoutProperties: AbsoluteLayoutProperties {
            positionX: 100
            positionY: 100   
        }               
    }   
}
```